# Does $BA = CA$ imply $B = C$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know this is too simple of a question, but I haven't been able to prove it by myself so here we are.

If $A, B^T, C^T \in \mathbb{R}^{D \times d}$ (with $D \ge d$) are full rank matrices, does $BA = CA$ imply $B = C$?

Comment: If $A$ is full rank, then the linear map $x \mapsto Ax$ is surjective. Hence $By=Cy$ for every $y \in \Bbb R^{d \times 1}$.

Comment: Maybe look at some examples for $d = 1$?

Answer (score 1):

No. In the case D = d, A = O is a good example.
In the D > d case, zero matrix is still a contradiction example for you guess.

Do you wanna consider full ranked matrices? I just tell a simple case which B = wC where w is a real non-zero scaler. A similar full-ranked A can make both sides 0 (prove: BA = 0 & BA = CA so BA = CA = 0. On the other hand, B = wC so BA = wCA = 0. w is not equal to zero, so CA is equal to zero. You can conclude in a briefer way).

This discussion can be continued. You need to consider boundary situations & trying to make a stronger conjecture.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Please check the 2nd paragraph. For making a matrix multiplication to be 0, being 0 isn't needed (like what we see in 0 dividers, in advanced algebra).

Comment: I see, I was confused about what you were saying since you started off by taking $A$ to be the zero matrix, and didn't explicitly give any other matrix as an example.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Please check this & if there's any mistake let me know. A = [2,-12;-4,0;2,4], B = [1,2,3;4,5,6]. Both of them are full rank matrices which is equal to 2, since max rank = min (d,D). Simply consider w=2 to create C (I wrote B = wC in my answer). Calculation for C isn't needed because scaler can be factored.

Comment: That example doesn't quite work: I get $-24$ in the bottom right entry of $BA$. Here is an example with $d=2$ and $D=4$: $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -2 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: (To get $BA = 0$ when $A$ and $B$ are full-rank matrices, we need $D \ge 2d$. To have $BA=0$, we want the column space of $A$ to be in the null space of $B$, but the column space of $A$ has dimension $d$ and the null space of $B$ has dimension $D-d$, so we want $d \le D-d$ or $D\ge 2d$. But the implication $BA = CA \implies B=C$ stops holding in general once $D > d$, just for other reasons.)